# How to check if scroll goes below some level?

Tags: javascript

I need to do something like this ->
If the scroll goes below 200px, change the page colour to red. If it is over 200px, change it to white.
How can I achieve this?

```
const event11 = window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(window.innerHeight);
  if(e.pageY < (window.innerHeight - 200)) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: Spamming tags doesnt help.

Comment: Shakered, solutions should be posted as an "answer".

Comment: I added code attempt in question

Comment: Note, you can scroll in many ways, not just mouse wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieved the scroll position with pure JavaScript `scrollY` & `scrollX` properties.

**Notes**

> The `pageXOffset` property is an alias for the `scrollX` property, and The
> `pageYOffset` property is an alias for the `scrollY` property

**Codepen Example**: https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/VwKWeRL

Below is example of same effect with `scroll` event listener:

```js
const event11 = window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(this.scrollY < 200) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find `scroll position` with `window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;`. Use it to compare with your expected height 200.

Also use `scroll` event instead of `wheel` because `wheel` event will only fire on mouse wheel scroll. If some one scrolls page with dragging scrollbar then it won't work. So use `scroll` event which will work on those case also.

Add `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'));` so initially it will trigger `scroll` event and set proper background color.

References : 1. [JavaScript get window X/Y position for scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll)

2. [How to trigger an on scroll event without scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879452/how-to-trigger-an-on-scroll-event-without-scrolling)

Try it below.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (top < 200) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});

// trigger scroll event when page loads.
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'));
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one property in DOM tree which shows scroll's current Y position called `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`.

```js
const event11 = window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  
  if(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 200) {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```